# Python, declaring variables as from enclosing blocks

Tags: python

What is the Python idiom for something like:

```
def F():
    waitfor = 5
    def f2(x):
        global2you waitfor # <<<<<<< SOMETHING FROM ENCLOSING_BLOCKS
        waitfor += 1
        return waitfor
    print "waitfor, before", waitfor, "and after", f2("ABCD")
F()
```

I am reluctant to use `global waitfor` because I don't want to have any name collisions with other developers' variable names. I am stuck with Python 2.6.9. Thanks.

Comment: An observation: if you are returning the value of `waitfor`, do you really need to update the variable defined in `F`?

Comment: @chepner this was just to illustrate my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, you can use the [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) keyword, which solves this problem cleanly.

In Python 2, however, you have to resort to a "poor man's reference", by turning `waitfor` into a list of one element:

```
def F():
    waitfor = [5]
    def f2(x):
        waitfor[0] += 1
        return waitfor[0]
    print "waitfor, before", waitfor[0], "and after", f2("ABCD")
```